# Excel VBA 2016 / 365 Compatibility Issues?

Tags: excel, vba, compatibility, excel-2016, excel-365

I made a macro that others have been using the last 6 months with 0 unexpected errors until yesterday.

This entire time the macro has been created, edited, and used with office 365.  All OS have Windows 10.  Yesterday someone tried using the macro on a different PC (Still Windows 10), but had Excel 2016.  They used the macro to import a file and encountered a `Mismatch` error, and the error line made no sense to me because it was just erasing a loaded array.

I commented out erasing the arrays and tried again, and it gave me another mismatch error on the first if statement of my code.

I took the same exact macro file and opened it on a PC that had Office 365 and the macro ran perfectly.

I'm not sure what's going on with 2016 vs 365 but I've been reading around and all the factors I can find, pertain to either the operating system or the project references.  Both seem to be fine to me.

Not sure if this is helpful information, but these are being used at work so the PC's are networked

Am I missing something?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

[image: error]

[image: errorline]

[image: references]

****** EDIT ******

```
Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Dim FileToOpen As Variant, ResultFile As Variant, xRet As Boolean, Name As String, SDInterpretation As Integer, CrtThresholdCutoff#
Dim QSResultFileWB As Workbook, QSResultFileWS As Worksheet, FormattingWS As Worksheet, ImptPtInfo As Worksheet, PullReruns As Worksheet
Dim SampleName As Range, QSTarget As Range, sampleArrayIK As Variant, sampleArrayDE As Variant, FormattingWBCrtLastRow As Long, FlaggedSpecimensLastRow As Long
Dim CrtAverage As Range, FlaggedSpecimens As Range, FinalResult As Range, FirstTarget As Range, SecondTarget As Range, AccessionNumber As Range
Dim FirstTargetCrtValue As Range, SecondTargetCrtValue As Range, CrtSDValue As Range, FinalCrt As Range, twenty As Integer
Dim NameChange As Range, NameChangeMatch As Variant, ElastRow As Long, UlastRow As Long, PreConvertedNames As Range, SampleNameLastRow As Long
Dim DEColumnRng As Range, IKColumnRng As Range, DLastRow As Long, QSNameMatch As Variant
Dim Counter As Long, SampleNameStart As Range, TotalRows As Integer, QCProblems As Range, QCProblemsLastRow As Long
Dim PostImportDLastRow As Long, EndPlateQSMatch As Variant, FindFullNameAndPosition As Range
Dim myPath As String, XenoControl As String, ColumnCRerunsLastRow As Long, ColumnBRerunsLastRow As Long
Dim ColumnBReruns As Range, ColumnCReruns As Range, RerunPatient As Range, RedBorderSearchRng As Range
Dim PositiveExtractionControl As String, NegativeExtractionControl As String, NegativeTemplateControl As String, PositiveTemplateControl5 As String
Dim NTCArr As Variant, PTC5Arr As Variant, PEC1Arr As Variant, NEC1Arr As Variant
Dim DERange As Range, IJKRange As Range, r As Range, ClearStartRangeLastRow As Long, ClearStartRange As Range
Dim SerialNumberRng As Range, OpenArraySerialNumber As String, PlateSerialNumber As Range

Dim LowLow As String, Low As String, Moderate As String, High As String, HighHigh As String, EstCopyNumber As Range
Dim PTC123Arr As Variant, PTC4Arr As Variant, PositiveTemplateControl2 As String, PositiveTemplateControl3 As String, PositiveTemplateControl4 As String, PositiveTemplateControl1 As String

    ChDrive "C"
    myPath = "C:\Users\j\OneDrive\Documents\Excel\UTM Open Array\Validation Files"   
    ChDir myPath

    PositiveExtractionControl = "PEC"
    NegativeExtractionControl = "NEC"
    NegativeTemplateControl = "NTC"
    PositiveTemplateControl5 = "PTC"

LowLow = "< 1,000 copies/uL (Low)"
Low = "1,000 - 10,000 copies/uL (Low)"
Moderate = "10,000 - 100,000 copies/uL (Moderate)"
High = "100,000 - 1,000,000 copies/uL (High)"
HighHigh = "> 1,000,000 copies/uL (High)"

        PEC1Arr = Array("Candida albicans", "Xeno")
        NEC1Arr = Array("Xeno")
        NTCArr = Array("Proteus vulgaris", "Acinetobacter baumannii", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Klebsiella oxytoca", "Enterobacter cloacae", _
                        "Enterococcus faecium", "Morganella morganii", "Providencia stuartii", "Citrobacter freundii", "Streptococcus agalactiae", "Enterococcus faecalis", _
                        "Escherichia coli", "Klebsiella aerogenes", "Coagulase-negative staphylococcus", "Candida albicans", "Xeno", "Proteus mirabilis", _
                        "ESBL", "DHA", "ampC/FOX/ACC", "IMP", "TEM/SHV/VEB", "OXA/GES/PER", "qnrA/qnrS", "OXA", "VIM/KPC", "Vancomycin")
        PTC5Arr = Array("Proteus vulgaris", "Acinetobacter baumannii", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Klebsiella oxytoca", "Enterobacter cloacae", _
                        "Enterococcus faecium", "Morganella morganii", "Providencia stuartii", "Citrobacter freundii", "Streptococcus agalactiae", "Enterococcus faecalis", _
                        "Escherichia coli", "Klebsiella aerogenes", "Coagulase-negative staphylococcus", "Candida albicans", "Xeno", "Proteus mirabilis", _
                        "ESBL", "DHA", "ampC/FOX/ACC", "IMP", "TEM/SHV/VEB", "OXA/GES/PER", "qnrA/qnrS", "OXA", "VIM/KPC", "Vancomycin")

        Set FormattingWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OpenArray Raw Data")

 FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select all files needing analyzed", MultiSelect:=True)       'if file types change to csv or something else, this needs changed
        If Not IsArray(FileToOpen) Then Exit Sub

                'clear import range
        With FormattingWS
            ClearStartRangeLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            Set ClearStartRange = FormattingWS.Range("D11:O" & ClearStartRangeLastRow)
            ClearStartRange.Clear
            .Range("A3:C500").Clear
        End With

        With FormattingWS
            .Range("D10").Value = "Sample Name"
            .Range("E10").Value = "Target Name"
            .Range("F10").Value = "Crt"
            .Range("G10").Value = "Crt Average"
            .Range("H10").Value = "Crt SD"
            .Range("I10").Value = "Serial Number"
            .Range("M10").Value = "Final Result"
            .Range("N10").Value = "Final Crt"
            .Range("O10").Value = "Estimated Copy Number"
            With FormattingWS.Range("D10:O10")
                .Font.Size = 14
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End With

                'select all result files at once
        For Each ResultFile In FileToOpen   '---------------------------------Import Result Files (Start)----------------------------
            Set QSResultFileWB = Workbooks.Open(ResultFile)
            Set QSResultFileWS = QSResultFileWB.Sheets("Results")

            TotalRows = 0
            Counter = 0

            With QSResultFileWS
                Set SampleName = .Range("A1:Q50").Find("Sample Name")
                SampleNameLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SampleName.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set SampleNameStart = .Range("D" & SampleName.Row).Offset(1, 0)

                With QSResultFileWS.Range("D" & SampleNameStart.Row, "D" & SampleNameLastRow)
                    For Each r In .Rows
                        If r.Value = vbNullString Then
                            GoTo CountNextRow
                        End If
                        If Application.CountA(r) <> 0 Then
                            Counter = Counter + 1
                        End If
CountNextRow:       Next r
                TotalRows = Counter
                End With
                OpenArraySerialNumber = QSResultFileWS.Range("B1").Value
                Set DERange = .Range("D21:E" & SampleNameLastRow)
                Set IJKRange = .Range("I21:I" & SampleNameLastRow)
                sampleArrayDE = DERange.Worksheet.Evaluate("FILTER(" & DERange.Address & "," & DERange.Columns(1).Address & "<>"""")")
                sampleArrayIK = IJKRange.Worksheet.Evaluate("FILTER(" & IJKRange.Address & "," & DERange.Columns(1).Address & "<>"""")")
            End With

            With FormattingWS
                DLastRow = FormattingWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
                Set DEColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("D" & DLastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                Set IKColumnRng = FormattingWS.Range("F" & DLastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                Set SerialNumberRng = FormattingWS.Range("I" & DLastRow).Offset(1, 0)
                FormattingWS.Range(DEColumnRng, "E" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayDE
                FormattingWS.Range(IKColumnRng, "F" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = sampleArrayIK
                FormattingWS.Range(SerialNumberRng, "I" & (DEColumnRng.Row + TotalRows) - 1).Value = OpenArraySerialNumber
            End With
                Erase sampleArrayDE
                Erase sampleArrayIK
            QSResultFileWS.Parent.Close False
        Next ResultFile                     '---------------------------------Import Result Files (End)-------------------------------

        Set ImptPtInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import Patient Information")
        Set PullReruns = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reruns To Pull")

        With PullReruns             '------------------------------Set Location on Reruns To Pull for Inconclusives + Reruns (Start)----------------------------------------
            .Range("A7:F2500").Clear
                ColumnBRerunsLastRow = PullReruns.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                ColumnCRerunsLastRow = PullReruns.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            Set ColumnBReruns = PullReruns.Range("C" & ColumnBRerunsLastRow).Offset(1, -2)
            Set ColumnCReruns = PullReruns.Range("F" & ColumnCRerunsLastRow).Offset(1, -2)
        End With                    '------------------------------Set Location on Reruns To Pull for Inconclusives + Reruns (End)----------------------------------------

        With FormattingWS
            FormattingWBCrtLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            ElastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            UlastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        Set PreConvertedNames = .Range("U1:U" & UlastRow)
            QCProblemsLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row       'change this to Columns A B and C
        Set QCProblems = .Range("C" & QCProblemsLastRow).Offset(1, 0)
            PostImportDLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Set RedBorderSearchRng = FormattingWS.Range("D1:D" & PostImportDLastRow).Cells
        End With
        With FormattingWS.Range("D11:E" & PostImportDLastRow, "M11:M" & PostImportDLastRow)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
        End With
        With FormattingWS.Range("F11:H" & PostImportDLastRow, "N11:N" & PostImportDLastRow)
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
        
        For Each NameChange In FormattingWS.Range("E11:E" & ElastRow).Cells     '-----------------------------Translate Target Names (Start)---------------------------------------
            NameChangeMatch = Application.Match(NameChange.Value, PreConvertedNames, 0) 'use helper columns in columns U and V on destination workbook to match/change names of everything in column e
                If Not IsError(NameChangeMatch) Then
                    With NameChange
                        .Value = FormattingWS.Cells(NameChangeMatch, 22)
                    End With
                End If
        Next NameChange                                                         '-----------------------------Translate Target Names (End)-----------------------------------------
        
        XenoControl = FormattingWS.Range("V28").Value
        SDInterpretation = 2        'if both target crt values are numbers then the SD must be <= 2.00 in order to be called detected
        twenty = 20
        
        For Each CrtAverage In FormattingWS.Range("G11:G" & FormattingWBCrtLastRow).Cells       '----------------------Result Interpretation Conditions(Start)--------------------------------------
           
           Set FirstTarget = CrtAverage.Offset(0, -2)
           Set SecondTarget = CrtAverage.Offset(1, -2)
           Set FirstTargetCrtValue = CrtAverage.Offset(0, -1)
           Set SecondTargetCrtValue = CrtAverage.Offset(1, -1)
           Set FinalResult = CrtAverage.Offset(0, 6)
           Set PlateSerialNumber = CrtAverage.Offset(0, 2)
           Set CrtSDValue = CrtAverage.Offset(0, 1)
           Set FinalCrt = CrtAverage.Offset(0, 7)
           Set AccessionNumber = CrtAverage.Offset(0, -3)
           Set EstCopyNumber = CrtAverage.Offset(0, 8)
        
            If FirstTarget.Value = SecondTarget.Value Then            'check 2 columns to the left, if this target and the target directly below are the same then
                    If FirstTarget.Value = "Coagulase-negative staphylococcus" Or FirstTarget.Value = "Xeno" Then
                        CrtThresholdCutoff# = 27.01
                    Else
                        CrtThresholdCutoff# = 30.01
                    End If
                If FirstTargetCrtValue.Value = "Undetermined" And SecondTargetCrtValue.Value = "Undetermined" Then
                    With FinalResult
                        .Value = "Not Detected"
                    End With
                    With FinalCrt
                        .Value = "0"
                    End With
                ElseIf IsNumeric(FirstTargetCrtValue.Value) = True And IsNumeric(SecondTargetCrtValue.Value) = True Then
                    With CrtAverage
                        .Value = Application.Average(FirstTargetCrtValue, SecondTargetCrtValue)
                    End With
                    With CrtSDValue
                        .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(FirstTargetCrtValue, SecondTargetCrtValue)
                    End With
                    If (FirstTargetCrtValue.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff) And (SecondTargetCrtValue.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff) Then
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = (CrtAverage.Value + CrtSDValue.Value)
                        End With
                        If FinalCrt.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Detected"
                                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                            End With
                        ElseIf FinalCrt.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Not Detected"
                            End With
                            With FinalCrt
                                .Value = "0"
                            End With
                        End If
                    ElseIf (FirstTargetCrtValue.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff And SecondTargetCrtValue.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff) Or _
                            (FirstTargetCrtValue.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff And SecondTargetCrtValue.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff) Then
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = (CrtAverage.Value + CrtSDValue.Value)
                        End With
                        
                        If (FinalCrt.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff And CrtSDValue.Value <= SDInterpretation) Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Detected"
                                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                            End With
                        ElseIf (FinalCrt.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff And CrtSDValue.Value <= SDInterpretation) Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Not Detected"
                            End With
                            With FinalCrt
                                .Value = "0"
                            End With
                        ElseIf (FinalCrt.Value <= CrtThresholdCutoff And CrtSDValue.Value > SDInterpretation) Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Not Detected"
                            End With
                            With FinalCrt
                                .Value = "0"
                            End With
                        End If
                    ElseIf (FirstTargetCrtValue.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff And SecondTargetCrtValue.Value > CrtThresholdCutoff) Then
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "0"
                        End With
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Not Detected"
                        End With
                    End If
                ElseIf IsNumeric(FirstTargetCrtValue.Value) = True And IsNumeric(SecondTargetCrtValue.Value) = False Then
                    With CrtAverage
                        .Value = Application.Average(FirstTargetCrtValue.Value, 0) 'find average of firsttargetcrtvalue & 0 (Undetermined)
                    End With
                    With CrtSDValue
                        .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(FirstTargetCrtValue.Value, 0)
                    End With
                    If FirstTargetCrtValue.Value <= twenty And (AccessionNumber.Value <> PositiveExtractionControl And AccessionNumber.Value <> NegativeExtractionControl _
                        And AccessionNumber.Value <> NegativeTemplateControl And AccessionNumber.Value <> PositiveTemplateControl5) Then
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "500"                                             'place 0 so specimen does not look like a positive in Ligo
                        End With
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Inconclusive"
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        End With
                        
                        PatientRerun (AccessionNumber & "," & FirstTarget)
                        
                    ElseIf FirstTargetCrtValue.Value <= twenty And (AccessionNumber.Value = PositiveExtractionControl Or AccessionNumber.Value = NegativeExtractionControl _
                            Or AccessionNumber.Value = NegativeTemplateControl Or AccessionNumber.Value = PositiveTemplateControl5) Then
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Inconclusive"
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        End With
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "500"
                        End With
                    ElseIf FirstTargetCrtValue.Value > twenty Then
                            With FinalResult
                                .Value = "Not Detected"
                            End With
                            With FinalCrt
                                .Value = "0"
                            End With
                    End If
                ElseIf IsNumeric(FirstTargetCrtValue.Value) = False And IsNumeric(SecondTargetCrtValue.Value) = True Then
                    With CrtAverage
                        .Value = Application.Average(SecondTargetCrtValue, 0)
                    End With
                    With CrtSDValue
                        .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(SecondTargetCrtValue, 0)
                    End With
                    If SecondTargetCrtValue.Value <= twenty And (AccessionNumber.Value <> PositiveExtractionControl) And (AccessionNumber.Value <> NegativeExtractionControl) _
                        And (AccessionNumber.Value <> NegativeTemplateControl) And (AccessionNumber.Value <> PositiveTemplateControl5) Then
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "500"
                        End With
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Inconclusive"
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        End With
                        
                        PatientRerun (AccessionNumber & "," & FirstTarget)
                        
                    ElseIf SecondTargetCrtValue.Value <= twenty And (AccessionNumber.Value = PositiveExtractionControl Or AccessionNumber.Value = NegativeExtractionControl _
                            Or AccessionNumber.Value = NegativeTemplateControl Or AccessionNumber.Value = PositiveTemplateControl5) Then
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Inconclusive"
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        End With
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "500"
                        End With
                    ElseIf SecondTargetCrtValue.Value > twenty Then
                        With FinalResult
                            .Value = "Not Detected"
                        End With
                        With FinalCrt
                            .Value = "0"
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
                If (FirstTarget = "Xeno" And FinalResult <> "Detected" And AccessionNumber <> PositiveExtractionControl And AccessionNumber <> NegativeExtractionControl _
                    And AccessionNumber <> PositiveTemplateControl5 And AccessionNumber <> NegativeTemplateControl) Then
                    PatientRerun (AccessionNumber & "," & FirstTarget)
                End If
```

The whole sub was too long, but the if statement where the error happened after commenting out erasing the arrays is the `If FirstTarget.Value = "Coagulase-negative staphylococcus" Or FirstTarget.Value = "Xeno" Then`

Comment: When the code halts at the `Erase` line, type `? TypeName(sampleArrayDE)` in the Immediate pane and press enter - what result do you get?   Would be helpful to show the declaration and assignment for that variable (no screenshots please...)

Comment: It's a variant.  Apologies Tim, I'll edit post with the entire sub.

Comment: Again, `? Typename(FirstTarget.Value)` should give you something useful.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  You mean when using 2016 and receiving the error.  I'll try it out Monday and see what I get.

Comment: `FILTER()` worksheet function is not available in Excel 2016...

Answer (score 1):

`Erase sampleArrayDE` will fail with "type Mismatch" if `sampleArrayDE` does not have a type which is compatible with `Erase`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/erase-statement

`Erase` can be called on a fixed-size array, or on a Variant with a subtype of Array, so in this case `TypeName(sampleArrayDE)` should give you `Variant()`

If it's not one of those types then it may be because your FILTER() call failed to return any records, in which case `TypeName()` will be `Error`, which is not compatible with `Erase`

Worth noting FILTER() is not available in Excel 2016, which I should have twigged earlier...